# Is it correct to use different tenses in a sentence? For example, Past Simple and Present Continuous

Tags: tenses

Guys!

I wanted to write smth like "I studied at the university and am writing a book". Then I stopped because I had doubts whether it is correct to combine different tenses.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think there is no issue you could do it, 
I studied at the university, and currently I am writing a book

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example sentence you have given does seem disconnected. If the book is related to your studies, then I would qualify the statement: "I studied at the university and am now writing a book". Use of different tenses in this way is otherwise fine.